# How to solve confilict with jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Tags: jquery

I write a vertical tab in my store home page, and I should use jquery-1.10.2.min.js. but it has confilict with other scripts and somethings showing wrong in store.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/395aabpk/5/) of vertical tab.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use noConflict

like

`var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: Add this in script of vertical tab?

Comment: no problem. set top of script and all $ convert to $j (only this script)

Comment: It doesn't work!!

Comment: If you've done as Abdus said and made sure all jquery files use $j instead of $, then also make sure 1. there is only one instance of jquery on the page 2. noconflict comes right after jquery is called. Otherwise can you provide the error message you see in the console?

Comment: I found where is the problem, I add `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` and I have `jquery-1.7.1.js` in theme. I remove `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` and use what Abdus said and all things work good.